# How to solve Parametric Equations with Trig functions that have attached coefficents to T

Tags: algebra-precalculus, parametric

Can anyone walk me through how to find the parametric curve for

x=3*sin(**2**t), y = 1.5*cos(t)?

If the parametric equations were x = 3*sin(t), y = 1.5*cos(t) I know I would solve it the following way:

x/3 = sin(t), y/1.5 = cos(t) --> 
(x/3)^2 + (y/1.5)^2 = 1

What's really confusing me is the 2 that is being multiplied to t.

Thanks in advance

Comment: As stated it's already a parametric curve. You don't have to do anything else to make it one.

Comment: Do you want a $r=f(t)$ polar form?

Comment: Welcome to math.SE!! Please use $\mathrm{\LaTeX}$ to write math correctly.

Comment: How do I write the math "correctly?" Is there a setting I need to use?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

$$\dfrac xy=4\sin t$$

So, $$(x/4y)^2+(2y/3)^2=1$$

Comment: Could you explain how you got x/y = 4*sin(t)?

Comment: @Hannah, $$\sin2t=2\sin t\cos t$$ now find $$\dfrac xy$$